# jQuery Tools Scroller with autoscroll & jQuery Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox, jquery-tools

I have implemented a simple scrollable photo-gallery with jQuery Tools.
I then attached the autoscroll behavior to the jQuery tools scroller to create a photo slide-show.
Then I attached the jQuery colorbox to the photo slide-show to provide a larger version of the images.

I'm running into the following problems.  I hope I can explain them with the best possible way since the behavior sometimes is unpredictable.

The major issue is that when I stop the slideshow and click on the image to bring the colorbox or the next/previous buttons the slideshow starts again. Is there a way to disable this behavior??

Another problem is that when I click on the colorbox it looks like there are 9 images instead of 7. You can see that by clicking on a photo and seeing the index that colorbox generates on the top right of the zoomed version of the photo.
Why is this happening? I cannot find an explanation.

Finally the most annoying part of all which has happened twice and I cannot reproduce is that jQuery tools scrollable at some point when you open and close colorbox it messes up the indexes and scrolls an additional step resulting into a blank non-existent photo .. this also messes up the display of the current photo number which is on the bottom left - the navigation.

I know that those two libraries are not necessarily meant to work together however I posted these questions here in case someone has done the same or a relative script.
Any help would be verry much appreciated.

Javascript code:

```
$("#gallery").scrollable({circular:true}).autoscroll({autoplay:true});
var api = $("#gallery").data("scrollable");
var indd = api.getIndex();

api.onSeek(function() {
    $("#cur-p").html(parseInt(api.getIndex()+1));
    $("#tot-p").html(api.getSize());
});

$("#slid").toggle(function() {
        api.stop();
        $(this).html("SLIDESHOW ON");
        return false;
    }, function() {
        api.play();
        $(this).html("SLIDESHOW OFF");
        return false;
    }

);

$("#cur-p").html(parseInt(api.getIndex()+1));
$("#tot-p").html(api.getSize());

$("a[rel=color-box]").colorbox();
```

* UPDATE ***
Up to now I have managed to figure out one of the strange behaviors.
Colorbox shows more total images than there are. This is because it is called after the autoscroll plugin. Autoscroll creates 2 extra divs one before the beginning and one after the end when the circular property is on. Thus colorbox finds them and adds them to the equation.

If I don't call autoscroll at all colorbox works fine.
So a solution would be to call colorbox like that:

```
$("#gallery").scrollable().find("a[rel=color-box]").colorbox();
```

and when colorbox has finished loading then apply the autoscroll plugin to the gallery.
however i'm not sure on how to apply the autoscroll on the already created scrollable instance.

Comment: This is a very old post but I am facing the same problem now as well. I need to be able to re-initialize colorbox after an ajax fetch because I cannot click to open images after they havebeen revealed with autopager